# asp.net help resource location

Tags: asp.net, xml, resources, web-config

I have a relatively simple site that I'm working up for an intranet environment. The pages have a hook to display a simple bit of text (possibly with a bit of HTML for markup purposes) for help when the user clicks a link on the page. I'm debating whether to put the help snippets in their own XML file or create a section in `web.config`. The site is to be deployed across several client sites and given that updating a web.config file appears to restart the site, I'm leaning toward having it in its own file. My question is where would be the best place to locate it? I'd rather it weren't easily web-accessible, so although root or some folder is an option, I'm wondering if there is a more "standard" location for files like this, `App_LocalResources` perhaps? Any feedback would be welcome. Thanks.

---

I will look at these options. I don't anticipate a lot of updates to the help file/resource, but I think as the function of the site expands, it's certainly possible. I like the idea of it being something like XML or at least editable in a text editor so that updating doesn't necessarily require VS to update the file. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect candidate for resx (resource) files in the App_GlobalResources folder. Those are easily editable and posted to a site without any restarts.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an embedded resource?  There are several tutorials around how to use embedded resources and package it up in a dll to distribute along with your website.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I connect the web application to an online help wiki wherever possible.

The .aspx page name is used as the help page title. Once you are in the wiki, you are free to do all the wiki tricks, such as redirecting and linking

See my [blog entry](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/04/28/online-help-for-web-applications/) for technical infos.